# Why can I not see the cloudbees github plugin

Tags: github, cloudbees

Trying to follow the instructions at http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/GitHub+Commit+Hooks+HOWTO

but I don't see the github plugin in the list of available or installed jenkins plugins.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, which I can't reproduce with my own free instance. Open a support ticket if you still don't see it.

Comment: interesting. I'm still not seeing it so I guess I'll open a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

The Cloudbeeds blog does list the [requirements](http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/01/better-integration-between-jenkins-and.html):

> #### Requirement for Plug-in Use
>
> - Jenkins 1.400 or newer
> - Jenkins Git Plugin version 1.1.12 or newer
> - At least one GitHub hosted project to build ;-)
>
> #### Step-by-Step Instructions on How to Use it: Installation
>
> - Go to your Jenkins instances root page.
> - If your Jenkins instance has security enabled, login as a user who has the Overall | Administer permission.
> - Select the Manage Jenkins link on the left-hand side of the screen.
> - Select the Manage Plugins link.
> - On the Available tab, select the Github Plugin and click the Download and Install button at the bottom of the page (if you do not got the Git Plugin installed, do not worry, Jenkins is smart enough to install/upgrade the Git plugin, where required).
> - Restart Jenkins once the plugins are downloaded (Note: users of Jenkins 1.442 or newer should be aware that the plugin currently requires a restart to function correctly).

So there could be many reasons (like the Jenkins version) why you don't see the [Jenkins GitHub plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin), the most usual one being to be logged on a non-Administor account.

---

As the [OP TomL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188306/toml) confirms in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13014001/6309), if the plugin is *still* not visible to be installed, only CB support can make it visible.

Comment: cloudbees is _hosted_ jenkins! Why would I need to worry about what version I'm running?

Comment: @TomL Ok, and did you have the right privilege associated with your account in order to see those plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I contacted CB support and they told me what the docs said: install the plugin. I go to confirm that I still don't have the plugin available to me, and it's now available. Not sure if they changed something or it was just a glitch, but I'm now able to follow the docs and get github working.

Comment: Excellent. At least it is working now. I have added your conclusion in my answer.